# How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand in 22.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

Yes, I know there's this question already.
But it's 10 years old and the proposed solution doesn't work for 22.04.
And without this stupid "karma" I can't even add a comment in there.
So my only option is to create a new question.

Ubuntu 22.04 ignores `~/.local/share/applications` completely and acts like it doesn't exist.

How can I create new launcher items in Unity by hand?

Answer (score 0):

`.desktop` files can be created as old as a correctly formatted text file with the `.desktop`  extension. It will be incorporated in the menu provided it is either in `~/.local/share/applications` or in one of the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` directories.

You state that `~/.local/share/applications` is ignored, but you did not provide evidence. A standard system will by default search first for user-specific `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`, or in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications` if that variable is set. If yours does not, then it is because you changed the related configuration of your system.

For a `.desktop` to appear in the user menu, it must be valid. The very least a valid `.desktop` file for an application should contain are valid entries for 1) `Name=`, 2) `Exec=` and 3) `Type=`.

So if you are quite certain you did not change your system configuration, check the validity of your `.desktop` file first.